# When is PyEval_InitThreads meant to be called?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I'm a bit confused about when I'm supposed to call `PyEval_InitThreads`.  In general, I understand that `PyEval_InitThreads` must be called whenever a non-Python thread (i.e. a thread that is spawned within an extension module) is used.

However, I'm confused if `PyEval_InitThreads` is for C programs which embed the Python interpreter, or Python programs which import C-extension modules, or both.

So, if I write a C extension module that will internally launch a thread, do I need to call `PyEval_InitThreads` when initializing the module?

Also, `PyEval_InitThreads` [**implicitly acquires the Global Interpreter Lock**](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/init.html#PyEval_InitThreads).  So after calling `PyEval_InitThreads`, presumably the GIL must be *released* or deadlock will ensue.  So how do you release the lock?  After reading the documentation, [**`PyEval_ReleaseLock()`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/init.html#PyEval_ReleaseLock) appears to be the way to release the GIL.  However, in practice, if I use the following code in a C extension module:

```
   PyEval_InitThreads();
   PyEval_ReleaseLock();
```

...then at runtime Python aborts with:

```
Fatal Python error: drop_gil: GIL is not locked
```

So how do you release the GIL after acquiring it with `PyEval_InitThreads`?

Comment: Try without the `PyEval_ReleaseLock()`.  The GIL is acquired for a good reason; releasing it before calling other C API functions from Python is going to crash.

Answer (score 3):

Most applications never need to know about `PyEval_InitThreads()` at all.

The only time you should use it is if your embedding application or extension module will be making Python C API calls from more than one thread *that it spawned itself* outside of Python.

Don't call `PyEval_ReleaseLock()` in any thread which will later be making Python C API calls (unless you re-acquire it before those).  In that case you should really use the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macros instead.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  Assuming you are embedding Python in a C program, and you have 20 worker threads, who should call PyEval_InitThreads, and how does each worker release the lock while it's off doing other things so other threads that need to do some Python work can get the GIL?

Comment: @DougN, yeah I agree.  The answer is vague (as are the Python docs themselves unfortunately)

Comment: If you are embedding Python i a C program, call it once for the entire program as you initialize your embedded Python interpreter before having it execute your first Python code.